# This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless; vertical and horizontal orientation

Tags: android

I have linear layouts

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1875b5"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AboutUs"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#186db5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

You can see all code here
**http://www.a2b4.net/linearlayout.txt**
not to have

`This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view` warning.

How i can merge not to have warning.

One is horizontal other vertical.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Did you get a warning message that said one of your layouts was useless? Also, please provide your whole layout file so that we can see how the parts are related.

Comment: here isthe all code http://www.a2b4.net/linearlayout.txt

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of layouts! For performance, and to avoid memory issues, it might be better to the left-of/right-of, etc. attributes for your RelativeLayout(s), GridView, or TableLayout. But I'll check out your existing approach...

Comment: The outer LinearLayout is indeed useless. Since your root view is relative layout, why not just position all the children(including the horizontal LL) accordingly? That outer LinearLayout really does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your outer LinearLayout; it adds nothing to your layout. Your can just delete the first set of these lines:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and the last line of:

```
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, add an id to the (new first) LinearLayout that defines what appears to be your heading line:

```
android:id="@+id/heading"
```

And finally a positioning attribute to the scrollview:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
```

Comment: if you have any suggetsion

Comment: I've updated my answer. With relative layouts, you can specify positions relative (above, below, leftOf, rightOf, etc.) to other items. There are a whole slew of positioning attributes that you can see at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html